# A cylinder and the area of its shadow

Tags: calculus, geometry, functions, area

A cylinder with base radius r and height h is placed on the x-y plane in a 3d coordinate system. A light travelling around a circular path in the x-z plane with radius R (R > r²+h²) from the origin is casting the cylinder's shadow on the x-y plane. When the light source is below the x-y plane, the shadow's area is 0. The length of the shadow is limited to 10h. What would be the average area of the cylinder's shadow once the light makes one full revolution around the circle? How does the radius of the light's path affect the average area?

[The 3d coordinate system with cylinder and light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oDkd.jpg)

[A side view of the coordinate system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhzBR.jpg)

What would be the difference in the average area in the case that the light is infinitely far away (the light rays are parallel)?

For context: I'm only in high school (4. grade in my country) and I came up with this in math class and have been wracking my brain trying to solve it. I can't possibly fathom the math needed to solve this although I'm really curious. I scoured the internet for the solution and I can't find anything.

Comment: One more issue: What will the area be when the light's point source has a $z$-coordinate of $0 < z < r$?  (to make the problem meaningful, we need to somehow ignore this region, but as of right now, we'd never be able to ignore it except when $R=\infty$)

Comment: @BrianMoehring Probably you meant $h$ not $r$. I think in this case the restriction "The length of the shadow is limited to 10h" applies, though the meaning of the "length" is not clear.

Comment: @user Yes, I meant $h$ instead of $r$.  That phrase was added after my comment, but similarly I don't know how to interpret it.  The least complicated way might be to have a circle of radius $10h+r$ centered at the origin in the $xy$-plane inside which we measure the shaded area.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Or it can mean that the shadow restricted by the lines $x=\pm10h$.